# Android: how to show a toast before forcing the closure of the app?

Tags: android

i've to show a toast and after to force the closure of the app if there isn't an internet connection, but if i show only the toast everything is ok:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nessuna connessione", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if i make this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nessuna connessione", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

the app is closed and the toast isn't show.

how i can show this toast and after close the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show the `Toast`:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

and then call finish:

```
finish();
```

Comment: i use it for close the app if there isn't internet connection in an async task and work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Instead of killing the process you can just call `finish()` in you `Activity`. This way your toast will be shown.